# "Неметено" — часть речи

Tags: словообразование, слитно-раздельно, части-речи

Впервые встретил слово *"неметено"* в книжке. Сразу возник вопрос об ударении, но потом вроде стало очевидно, что ударение на О. Верно?

Нашёл на Грамоте слова *["неметёный"](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x)* и *["не метённый"](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9).* *В чём между ними разница?* Только в том, что к причастию "не метённый" могут быть зависимые слова (например, "не метённый **веником** пол")? Правильно тогда я понимаю, что если нет зависимых слов, то должно быть прилагательное "неметёный"?  Тогда, выходит, в следующем примере причастие выбрано неправильно?[image]

Имеет ли вообще право на существование слитное *"неметено"?* Или можно писать только раздельно, *"не метено"?* Примеров с раздельным написанием в "google книгах" гораздо больше: 120 против 3. Если слитно тоже писать можно, то в чём разница, и какой частью речи будет это *"неметено"?* Неужели тоже *кратким причастием?!*

Answer (score 2):

***Не метено*** - краткое причастие, пишется с НЕ раздельно. Слитное написание невозможно.
***Давно не метённый пол*** - написание верное, у причастия есть зависимое слово ДАВНО.

Comment: Спасибо, Екатерина! Не сообразил, что "давно" — зависимое слово. Скажите всё-таки, пожалуйста, правильно, что "не метённый" с зависимыми словами, а "неметёный" — без? И что второе слово ничем не "хуже".

Comment: Да, верно. Неметёный пол вызывал его раздражение. Вполне приемлемый вариант. Отглагольное прилагательное, а вот краткая форма может быть только у качественного прилагательного,значит, "неметено" невозможно.

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила! Вот я и удивлялся, когда увидел это слитно написанное слово, мне оно сразу показалось странным!